# PictureBox with shadow

Tags: c#, .net, picturebox

How would I go about adding a drop shadow to a PictureBox?

Comment: maybe it can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021050/c-sharp-winforms-panel-with-same-style-shadow-as-tabcontrol

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743926/how-can-i-add-a-shadow-around-a-form-with-no-border/14743974#14743974